# I have a date property in javascript here i need the expired date should be shown in red color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors

Here i have 4 different dates in my html the expired date END MAR 20 should be in red color instead of green and the next date should be of green color ie END ARP 29 and all the other preceding dates should be of red color, i have achieved till the date filteration but i need the expired date should be in red color

```js
var date = $(".grid-item").map(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim()
}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var f = function(date) {
    var m, d, y;

    if (date.startsWith("END")) {
      date = date.split(" ");
      var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
      m = months.indexOf(date[1]) + 1;
      d = date[2];
    } else [y, m, d] = date.split("-");
    

    return [(new Date()).getFullYear(), m, d];
  }
  var t = new Date();
  return Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(a)).getTime()) - Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(b)).getTime());
});


$(".grid-item").addClass('red').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === date[0];
}).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item">END MAY 29</div>
<div class="grid-item">END SEP 29</div>
<div class="grid-item">END MAR 20</div>
<div class="grid-item">END APR 29</div>
```

Comment: What exactly fails?

Comment: actually  in map function it will store all the dates and it will return the index  return $(this).text().trim() === date[0]; for the most recent dates in green color but i dont want to show the expired date in green color

Comment: @Kunalshetty your approach is basically wrong. Relying on text for numerical or date calculations is not solid, not safe, and hard to read. Use zero-based month values like Javascript `Date` object, and store these values in element attributes. Then do the calc on these values.

Example: `<div class="grid-item" data-month="2" data-day="29">END MAY 29</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a demo to print expired date. However you could do it by using some jQuery code but I used pure javascript because Javascript is more faster and obvious choice to code when performance needs consideration.

```js
 
 var current = new Date();
 var currentDate = current.getDate();
 var currentMonth = current.getMonth();
 var currentYear = current.getFullYear();

     document.getElementById("date").value = currentDate;
     document.getElementById("month").value = currentMonth+1;
     document.getElementById("year").value = currentYear;

    function fun(){
     getDays();
     }
 
 
     function getDays(){       
    var date = ((document.getElementById("date").value) == "") ? currentDate : parseInt(document.getElementById("date").value);
    var month = ((document.getElementById("month").value) == "")?currentMonth : parseInt(document.getElementById("month").value-1);
    var year= ((document.getElementById("year").value) == "")?currentYear : parseInt(document.getElementById("year").value); 
    var d = new Date(year,month,date); 
  
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = d;
  if(((currentYear<=year )&&(currentMonth<month)) ||(currentYear<year ) || ((currentYear==year )&&(currentMonth==month)&&(currentDate<=date)) ){
   document.getElementById("day").style.color = "green";
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById("day").style.color = "red";
  }
       }
  getDays();
```

```html
  input date
<input type="number" value = ""  id="date" onchange="fun()"/>
input month<input type="number" value = ""  id="month" onchange="fun()"/>
input year<input type="number" value = ""  id="year" onchange="fun()"/>
<p id="day"></p>
```

Comment: In the above metioned snippet i want the END APR 29 to be highlighted with green color insteated of red because it is expired

Comment: Yeh you are right.. javascript is winner everytime.